# RxAndroid interval with FlatMap trigger CALL twice instead once

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

**CODE**

```
 heartBeatSub = Observable.interval(HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Notification<Response>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Notification<Response>> call(Long aLong) {
                    return api.requestHeartBeat(vehicleId).materialize();
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Notification<Response>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Notification<Response> responseNotification) {
                    Log.i("HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL", "Response from HEARTBEAT");
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    // TODO: 22/03/16 ADD ERROR HANDLING
                }
            });
```

**PROBLEM**

My `call` method is triggered twice instead once per interval.

```
03-22 11:57:47.236 28078-28078/com.app I/HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL: Response from HEARTBEAT
03-22 11:57:47.876 28078-28078/com.app I/HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL: Response from HEARTBEAT
```

First one i carring: `Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate rx.Notification.toString()`
And is called `onNext`.

Second one is normal `Response`.
And is called `onCompleted`

**========FIXED CODE==========**

With @Daniel Lew help I fixed my code and now it's working correctly

```
  private void triggerHeartBeat(final String vehicleId) {
    heartBeatSub = Observable.interval(HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Response>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Response> call(Long aLong) {
                    return api.requestHeartBeat(vehicleId);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Response response) {
                    Log.i("HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL", "Response from HEARTBEAT");
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    // TODO: 22/03/16 ADD ERROR HANDLING
                }
            });
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `materialize` here? Two events seem fine to me: one `onNext` event and one `onCompleted`, what else to expect after `materialize`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't call `materialize()`. It lifts all notifications (`onNext()`, `onCompleted()`, and `onError()`) into their own `onNext()` calls, with negative effects here.

Each API request inside of the `flatMap()` is a complete `Observable`, meaning that it both calls `onNext(response)` and `onCompleted()`. Normally `flatMap()` would not forward `onCompleted()` (since `interval()` hasn't completed yet), but since you call `materialize()` all notifications get forwarded to the subscriber.

In other words, you're getting this:

1. Notification (of onNext (with your Response))
2. Notification (of onCompleted)

If you didn't use `materialize()` you'd get what you want:

1. onNext (with your Response).

Comment: Thanks a lot mate that fixed my problem.
Also thanks for explaining the problem, looks like I didn't undestand `materialize()` correctly.